# Rudin functional analysis problem

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

-rudin-2th.pdf">http://59clc.files.wordpress.com/2012/08/functional-analysis--rudin-2th.pdf

1) page 326, he says that if ST=TS, then S commutes with f(T). He has previously shows that if S commutes with T, it commutes with the whole algebra, and in this case commutes with every projection E(w). How does it follow it commutes with f(T)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I correctly understood your question because I don't own Rudin's book. However, if you understood why $S$ commutes with every spectral projection $E(W)$, then the fact that $S$ commutes with $f(T)$ follows from the following reason. Every $f\in L^\infty$ is the norm limit of finite linear combination of simple function (i.e. $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \chi _{Y_i}$). Then it follows that $f(T)$ is the norm limit of finite linear sum of spectral projections $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i E(Y_i)$. As $S$ commutes with every finite sum, it follows that it commutes with the limit.

Comment: Could you explain why $S$ commutes with every spectral projection? To me it seems like he is trying to infer from $\int x d\mu(x) = \int x d\nu (x)$ that $\mu=\nu$.